# How to host SVN server on Cloud

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svn-server

I'm utilizing SVN for version control. To facilitate this, I've designated one laptop as a server, while two other laptops are functioning as clients. However, it's important to note that the server laptop must remain powered on at all times for the system to operate smoothly, as it functions within the network.

I want to keep my SVN server on clode, could you pleaese all guide me how to do this and which is best way to make it cloud based SVN server

Comment: [What is the best way to Host SVN on cloud?](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/ogoar3/what_is_the_best_way_to_host_svn_on_cloud/)